# Can someone explain to me why this emberjs observeable doesn't get fired?

Tags: ember.js

Whenever I save data **( self.get('content').pushObject(record);)** and push the record back into the content Array, the observable doesn't get fired. I need the observable to fire so the content array gets sorted again. Can you please explain to me why its not firing?

```
saveIdea.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    appName: 'My First Example',
    todaysDayOfMonth: moment().format('DD'),
    todaysMonth: moment().format('MMMM'),
    body: '',
    taggy: '',
    content : Em.A(),
    sortContent : function()
    {
        var ideas = this.get('content').toArray();
        ideas.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (moment(b.get('date')).isBefore(moment(a.get('date')))) {
                return -1
            } else {
                return 1
            }
        });
        this.set('content',ideas)
    },
    todaysIdeas: function(){
            this.sortContent();
    }.observes('content.[]'),
    actions: {

        save: function() {

            var self = this;

            var idea = this.store.createRecord('idea', {
                body: this.get('body'),
                tag: this.get('taggy')
            });
            idea.save().then(function(record) {
                self.get('content').pushObject(record);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd just use insertion sorting here, it'd be cheaper than resorting the content each time.

Comment: This also looks like an infinite loop, is it throwing an error?

Comment: And Em.A() returns a pointer to a collection, which will live on the class, so it would be shared amongst all instances of that collection.. At least initially

Comment: And You shouldn't really use `content` that was "deprecated" per say, you should just always use model.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bafoqodoyu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't use an Array.

> This mixin implements Observer-friendly Array-like behavior. It is not a concrete implementation, but it can be used up by other classes that want to appear like arrays.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html

Use a concrete implementation, e.x. `Ember.ArrayProxy`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

Comment: note that when using ember any javascript array will gains access to Ember.Array methods : [ By default, Ember.js will extend the prototypes of native JavaScript objects in the following ways:

Array is extended to implement the Ember.Enumerable, Ember.MutableEnumerable, Ember.MutableArray and Ember.Array interfaces. ]  __ so you can remplace your `content : Em.A()` by a [] ...

Comment: You can use an array just fine in an array controller, array controller already extends array proxy, that's how it proxies items down to the model instead of on itself